# ERC-20 Token Transfer Error : Bad jump destination

Tags: web3js, ether

I'am trying to send ERC20 from 1 address to another but i'am getting that error :

> Blockquote
>   Contract 0x557e4cca38277b9bf9f1f1bf333dfe4b0ac5541a 
>    Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination] 
>     ERC-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate Corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender. 
>   Blockquote

Here my code, can you help me to find the issue please ?

```
  var address = req.body.address;

  var contractAddress = "0x557e4cca38277b9bf9f1f1bf333dfe4b0ac5541a"
  var fromAddress = myaddress
  var privateKey = privatekey
  var toAddress = req.body.address
  var transferAmount = 1;

// Create an async function so I can use the "await" keyword to wait for things to finish
const main = async () => {
  // This code was written and tested using web3 version 1.0.0-beta.26
  console.log(`web3 version: ${web3.version}`)

  // Determine the nonce
  var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress);
  console.log(`num transactions so far: ${count}`);

  // This file is just JSON stolen from the contract page on etherscan.io under "Contract ABI"
  var abiArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './tt3.json'), 'utf-8'));
  // This is the address of the contract which created the ERC20 token
  var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, { from: fromAddress });
  //var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, { from: myAddress });

  // How many tokens do I have before sending?
  var balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(fromAddress).call();
  console.log(`Balance before send: ${balance}`);
  // I chose gas price and gas limit based on what ethereum wallet was recommending for a similar transaction. You may need to change the gas price!
  var rawTransaction = {
      "from": fromAddress,
      "nonce": "0x" + count.toString(16),
      "gasPrice": 2000000000,
      "gasLimit": 300000,
      "to": contractAddress,
      "value": transferAmount,
      "data": contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, transferAmount).encodeABI(),
      "chainId": web3.eth.net.getId()
  };

  // Example private key (do not use): 'e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109'
  // The private key must be for myAddress
  var privKey = new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex');
  var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
  tx.sign(privKey);
  var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

  // Comment out these three lines if you don't really want to send the TX right now
 console.log(`Attempting to send signed tx:  ${serializedTx.toString('hex')}`);
  var receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
  console.log(`Receipt info:  ${JSON.stringify(receipt, null, '\t')}`);

  // The balance may not be updated yet, but let's check
  balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(fromAddress).call();
  console.log(`Balance after send: ${balance}`);
}

main();
```

Comment: You make up a contract address (`0x55`) which obviously no contract is deployed at, and you're surprised to get a "bad jump" error?

Comment: Here the contract address : 0x557e4cca38277b9bf9f1f1bf333dfe4b0ac5541a

Comment: Well why are you using `var contractAddress = "0x55"`???

Comment: I follow an example from that website https://medium.com/bitfwd/how-to-issue-your-own-token-on-ethereum-in-less-than-20-minutes-ac1f8f022793

Comment: var contractAddress = "0x55" was only for that example. I used the entire address

Comment: Then you should write the correct code. Both 55 and 899 look like made-up addresses.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Please verify that `contractAddress == contract._address`.

Comment: Also, `"value": transferAmount` is definitely wrong. ERC20 function `transfer` is not `payable`. It only transfers token from one account to another. No ETH should be sent to the function (and the function will revert otherwise).

Comment: It is : 
`code`console.log(contract.address) == 0x557e4Cca38277B9BF9f1F1BF333DfE4B0ac5541a`code`

Comment: BTW, you don't need double quotes on key names. For example, you can use `from:` instead of `"from":`. In addition, `gasLimit` should be `gas` AFFAIK (though perhaps both work fine).

Comment: Thanks ! I removed "value" and now issue is solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning a comment into an answer:

ERC20 function `transfer` is not `payable`.

It only transfers tokens from one account to another.

There is no need to send ETH to this function, and moreover, doing so will cause it to revert.

So using `"value": transferAmount` with `transferAmount > 0` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is the `javascript` you've used to generate & sign the transaction, but the error is a `solidity` error. And it is very likely due to the fact that your contract address is `0x55`, which is somewhat short of an actual, `20 byte` long ethereum address. And so you're getting a bad jump destination error because there's no code *at all* at the `0x55` destination you've supplied.

Instead, for your code to work, you'll need an [actual ERC20 contract](https://openzeppelin.org/api/docs/token_ERC20_ERC20.html) deployed to your network of choice, whose *real* address you can then use.

Comment: I didn't write the entire address on previous sample code. Here the real contract address  0x557e4cca38277b9bf9f1f1bf333dfe4b0ac5541a